# Converting a batch script to Visual Basic

Tags: vba, batch-file

I just wanted to know how to convert this:

```
@echo off
:start
taskkill /f /im myProgram.exe
pause
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyFolder\myProgram.exe"
exit
```

to Visual Basic.

Comment: And I want a pony...

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Basic Script (.vbs file), you would need to use [WScript.Run](http://ss64.com/vb/run.html)

To convert your code literally line for line, you would do something like:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "C:\windows\system32\taskkill.exe /f /im myProgram.exe", 1, true
objShell.Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyFolder\myProgram.exe"
```

The first command waits for the taskkill to complete before running the next command... this simulates the pause.

If you wanted to keep the pause, you could use:

```
objShell.Sleep 2000 'Sleeps for 2 seconds
```

If you want to run this as a compiled VB application, the same code could work (if you're feeling lazy) or you could look at [This](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5879) which is a pre-canned function and does what you need it to (you can easily tweak this to shell a taskkill and task load.

Comment: Why not just use builtin [`Shell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278437.aspx)?